# Tension question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A mountain climber, in the process of crossing between two cliffs by a rope, pauses to rest. She weighs 581 N. As the drawing shows, she is closer to the left cliff than to the right cliff, with the result that the tensions in the left and right sides of the rope are not the same. Find the tensions in the rope to the left and to the right of the mountain climber. (From the figure α = 68.0° and β = 85.0°.)

[image: http://imgur.com/a/x97KL]

I keep getting T1 = 1696.77 and T2 = 1579.23 which keeps coming up as incorrect.

My work:

```
      Let T1 = left side
      Let T2 = right side

      Y: T1 * Cos(68) + T2 * Cos(85) = 581
      X: T1 * Sin(68) = T2 * Sin(85)

     T1 = T2*(Sin(85))/Sin(68))

     T2 * (Cos(68) * Sin(85))/(Sin(68) + Cos(85)) = 581
```

can anyone else help me with this problem? I'm not completely sure that I have the equations right because I checked the math multiple times

Comment: The equations seem correct to me,i don't think there is any error.

Comment: hmm not sure why it keeps coming up incorrect, perhaps I entered the values wrong

Comment: Could it be the computer doesn't like it when you enter too many significant digits?

Comment: Are you using the degrees mode of your calculator?

Comment: I don't think the amount of sig figs is the problem and yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parentheses are wrong.  I suspect you made the mistake when you substituted the expression for $T_1$ into your first equation.  You got
\begin{equation}
  T_2 \left( \frac{\sin 85^\circ\, \cos 68^\circ}{\sin 68^\circ  + \cos 85^\circ} \right) = 581\, \mathrm{N}.
\end{equation}
Instead, that equation should look like this:
\begin{equation}
  T_2 \left( \frac{\sin 85^\circ\,  \cos 68^\circ}{\sin 68^\circ} + \cos 85^\circ \right) = 581\, \mathrm{N}.
\end{equation}
With that, I get $T_2 = 1190\, \mathrm{N}$ and $T_1 = 1270\, \mathrm{N}$.